# How can I test my kik bot before submitting it for review

Tags: bots, kik

I want to test my kik bot functionality before submitting it for review and turning it to be live in production.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

When you first build a Bot on Kik it is limited to 50 users. You can push things live whenever you want to test.

You can also use the tool https://ngrok.com/ to create a webhook that links to your local laptop if you don't want to be deploying code all the time in development